# How to work with SQL Server stored procedures using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I'm new to programming using stored procedures and Entity Framework. I have created a SQL Server database with a table called `dbo.Book` which will hold the book title and an auto incremental ID column.

I have created a stored procedure to insert a record to `dbo.Book` and to return the `ID` column value of the newly entered record:

```
USE [Testing1DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspAddBook
    @title NVARCHAR(50),
    @bookId INT OUTPUT      
AS
BEGIN       
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.Book (TItle) 
    VALUES (@title)    

    SELECT @bookID = @@IDENTITY
END
```

When I move into Visual Studio and add Entity Framework Data Model to my C# Windows Forms project using my existing database, it generates a `...Context.cs` code related to my stored procedure as follows:

```
public virtual int uspAddBook(string title, ObjectParameter bookId)
{
    var titleParameter = title != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("title", title) :
                new ObjectParameter("title", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("uspAddBook", titleParameter, bookId);
}
```

My problem is, this method requires 2 parameters. 1 is the title which I can pass from my code, and another parameter denotes by 'bookId' which I don't know what is, because what I wanted is to pass only the title of the book and get the `book_ID` in return. So, I can't call the method 'uspAddBook' because I don't know what to send as he second parameter. Please help me.

Comment: Try `return Convert.ToInt32(bookId.Value);` in `uspAddBook` Method.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of `@@IDENTITY`  to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @Jenish, Where exactly do I need to put your suggested code?

Comment: @marc_s , I first tried using 'SCOPE_IDENTITY()'. But no luck. :(

Comment: Note that setting up all kinds of stored procedures so you can do procedural access to the database, kind of defeats the purpose of using the Object-Relational-Mapping paradigm, unless you only want to really make use of the advanced querying capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up an `ObjectParameter`...

```
ObjectParameter bookId = new ObjectParameter("bookID", typeof(Int32));//check type
context.uspAddBook("Title", bookId);
Int newBookId = bookId.Value;
```

Or, you can just use EF like this....

```
  context.Book.AddObject(title);
  context.SaveChanges();
  Int bookId = title.bookId;
```

I haven't tested any of this, but it's along the right lines...

Comment: I have tried the 1st suggestion. But it underlines the 'Integer' keyword in 'typeof(Integer)'. And also I need an integer return value. So how can I convert 'var' type into 'int' type?

Comment: I have updated, the `typeof` is now `int`, I added a comment for you to check the type.  The `var` keyword is *implicit*, so you don't need to convert anything.

Comment: It doesn't identify `Int` so I used `Int32` and it worked. Thanks @christiandev

Comment: OK, I had no way to validate - but I have updated the answer to reflect - glad it helped.